# Django : timezone.now() is inappropriate even after making timedate object aware

Tags: django, django-timezone

Datetime objects are stored in UTC and are converted to local timezone while displaying.
So when I call `timezone.now()`, it should convert the UTC to local timezone and display the time accordingly.

I have installed `pytz` as recommended by django.

I did the following :

Set `USE_TZ = True` in `settings.py`

and in `models.py` where I save the object to database

`from django.utils import timezone
 time= timezone.now()`

Also did `timezone.activate(pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))`

When I fetch the stored time,it is `2014-10-01 00:50:37`, which is some hours ahead of present time.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time stored in database was in UTC which is right. Problem was when I was retrieving it, it wasn't being converted to local timezone, it was printing in UTC.
So i had to convert it in the template as below:

```
{% load tz %}
{{ value|timezone:"America/Los_Angeles" }}
```

Phew, it worked!